# how to shutdown/stop scheduler after a specific time

Tags: python

I am creating a job which should run after every 10 seconds for next 2 hours, how can I do that?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()   
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=10)
  def timed_job():
     print('This job is run every 10 seconds.')
sched.start()
```

How can I stop this scheduled job to stop after 2 hours?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `time` built-in module. You can do `start_time = time.time()` to get the start time. Then do a boolean test before running your code of `if time.time()-start_time < 7200` and then your code. Otherwise it would cancel. Then your code will continue to run until 7200 seconds(2 hours) has passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def hello():
    print("hello-world ")

start_time = time.time()
while(time.time() - start_time < 20):
    hello()  
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/questions/44955880/how-to-shutdown-stop-scheduler-after-a-specific-time/63592325)